# Route TOR traffic to proxy gaining static IP address

Tags: exit-relays, ip-address

I would like to make my traffic less traceable, but on the outside looking statically mapped to one IP address. For example, me going to a website though TOR would result in requests being sent though different TOR exit nodes, as far as I understand, which makes for different IP addresses for each request. However, I would like the website to see the same static IP address all the time, so I would like to use a proxy at the end of the chain.

How could this be achieved? Should I then write my own proxy server? For example, it would accept traffic with some additional header (the destination header), unpack it and send it to the destination, and then, on request reception it would route the traffic back to the tor network.

It seems like a valid option, though I'm hoping for other, less time-consuming and resourse demanding, answers.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That would make you fingerprintable, removing your anonymity. Sure, websites won't know your real IP address, but they can tell that the same user is visiting so-and-so website. Using a proxy can make you trackable. I recommend against doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could this be achieved? Should I then write my own proxy server? For example, it would accept traffic with some additional header (the destination header), unpack it and send it to the destination, and then, on request reception it would route the traffic back to the tor network.

This is what a SOCKS proxy does, there's no need to write it yourself. Just run a SOCKS proxy and connect to it through Tor. Be careful about running publicly available SOCKS proxy servers though since they may be abused by others.

```
$ torsocks curl -x socks5h://publicsocksip:8001 https://www.google.com/
```